# "output from your job" after set ssmtp at a specific time

Tags: email, cron, at-job, ssmtp

I have a script that executes the program and send outputs via email to designated individuals. To

The script ran fine, just as expected, but after every script there is an auxiliary email sent to

`<localUsername>@gmail.com`

I have tried to play around `/etc/aliases` but it doesn't work so well. This is a very similar with me 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283504/how-to-disable-mailed-output-for-an-at-job

but it also does not work. Is there any solution to turn off this email feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a look the manual, `man at`, tells that `at -M` will disable emailing to one's self.